# Duplicate REST requests to second endpoint

Tags: http, rest, apache-camel

In order to test how a REST service performs under load I would like to send production data to two service end points, one production service and one test service.  I would like the responses from the test service to be ignored so the client has no idea it's request is being sent to 2 services.  I would like something in between the client and the service so that I do not need to make any changes to either, just have some sort of additional 'filter' service that the traffic will go through which will then pass the request on untouched but also send a duplicate request to the test service.  Someone suggested that I might be able to do this using Apache Camel but it's a bit overwhelming and I don't want to get started learning Camel if my aim is not possible.  Has anyone achieved anything similar, either using Camel or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by defining a jetty or a cxf endpoint that acts as a proxy routing the request to two other http endpoints ie, the REST services.

```
from("jetty:http://somehost:8282/xxx").
     to("http://prod:8181/rest/service/xyz").
          to("http://test:8182/rest/service/xyz");
```

The client can fire the load to `http://somehost:8282/xxx`. The client will not be aware that it is being routed to two services.

**Note:** The test will not yeild a real load result if you are routing the client request to two services via the above route or other proxy/router methodologies. Because some latency will be introduced by the proxy/route itself. Instead i suggest to use some load test tool to generate the  load and directly fire to the prod and test endpoints separately.

For example, apache ab benchmark tool. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372739/camel-jetty-benchmark-testing-for-requests-per-second) and [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

Comment: Surely the latency will be minimal, no?  I don't mind if there is a small reduction in speed but I wanted this type of load testing because I need lots of different types of request that will do real things in the background and hit my DB (actually I am testing something else's performance on my DB while it is under load but this type of test will be useful in the future anyway).  Do you still suggest that a proper load testing tool would be better?

Comment: It might be fine if you want to test the load when the request passes through all the service interactions and db transactions. Its like load testing the service or app itself. If i wanted to test a specific component behavior under load, I prefer to load test only that component.